# My wallet is blocked

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, smart-contract-wallets, wallet-transfer

Someone had access to my wallet. I don't know what happened that my property is frozen! Do you know a solution to release it?
https://etherscan.io/address/0x4DE23f3f0Fb3318287378AdbdE030cf61714b2f3

Comment: If you can't transfer out tokens cause someone is draining all gas, you have to use flashbots.

Comment: How can I remove this setting? I want to transfer my assets to an exchange

Comment: Nevermind, you're just trying to scam. This is a well known address, there's a thread here https://twitter.com/proof_of1/status/1508389078298992641